# How can I force an UILabel to update its text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I am using Swift to write code for iOS. When I click a button I want to set the text in an UILabel to change twice; once when we enter the function call and a second time just before the call is done. Something like this:

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // 1. Display "Please Wait..." in a UILabel

    // 2. Compute a value by calling a function 
    //    (it is slow, takes several seconds so 
    //    we need the please wait text to tell 
    //    the user it is doing something)

    // 3. Display the results from the computation 
    //    in the same UILabel as above
```

The problem I run into is that setting the UILabel's text (`myLabel.text = "Please Wait"`) before I call the slow function and then setting it again when the result is in will ONLY show the result text because the program did not re-draw the screen after the first setting of it ("Please Wait" text). Apple mentions that it only uses the last update to the `.text` property so it is an expected behavior. What is the simplest way to accomplish what I want to do in my function? I don't know much about threads as I am a beginner so go easy on me. :) Is there a magic function I can call after I set the text "Please Wait..." so that it updates the UILabel immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you need this structure

```
self.display.text = "wait" 
 // do task in background queue like 
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   callSlow() 
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.display.text = "done" 
   }
}
```

As it appears that your long calculation occurs in main thread so it blocks updating the label

Comment: You generally shouldn't use the `.background` QoS. It can be CPU starved in certain conditions (in particular if low power mode is active). `.userInitiated` is probably a better QoS for this use case.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much Sh_Khan!!!! That worked like a charm! Now I just have to read up on what is actually happening in your code. Awesome!!

Comment: Interesting observation... With the code structure mentioned above my slow function now takes 2-3 times as long to complete... It seems that adding a separate thread this way comes with a performance penalty. I wonder if there is a way around this...

Comment: Paul - Awesome! If I change the QoS to .userInitiated I regain my speed. The .background QoS was 2-3 times slower! Awesome! Many thanks to you and Sh_Khan!